# Can't serve static files using express.Router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Before my file system got a bit more complicated, I used to serve static files through `app.use(express.static())`. Now, I'm using `express.Router()` and I thought I could just change `app.use(express.static())` to `router.use(express.static())`, but it doesn't work. It throws an error: `Refused to apply style from ... because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Is there a way I can serve static files with `router.use()` instead of `app.use()`?

Filesystem:

```
/
..../chat
......../register
............/styles
................styles.min.css <-- This is the static file I want to serve
............index.html
............index.js
..../routes
........index.js
....index.js
```

/routes/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/chat/register', require('../chat/register'));

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.redirect('/chat/register'));

module.exports = router;
```

/chat/register/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/styles', express.static('styles'));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(require('./routes'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);

console.log(`App is listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 80}`);
```

Sorry if the question is badly-worded or something in the code looks out of line; this is my first time posting to Stack Overflow and I'm also kinda new to Node, Express, and web servers. I learn to program on my own time.

Comment: How do you link the CSS in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

> the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process.

So to take this into account, you should modify **chat/register/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.use('/styles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles')));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your path for the css, as this will be loaded by the server so that use the relative path for server as below.

In your `index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.use('/styles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles')));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

module.exports = router;
```